# Remove the whole array elements, where array element key count < 2 in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

Below is my code that output this array:

```
 // update users
$where_in = array('1102','');
$admin_data = $this->db->select('id,email,domain')->where_in('id',$where_in)->get('users')->result();

echo "<pre>";print_r($admin_data);
```

> current output array

```
1102,
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
        )

)
1111, 
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1132
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1133
        )

)
```

I am trying to accomplish by doing this, but not getting expected result.

```
foreach ($admin_data as $key) {

    if (count($admin_data) < 2) {
        unset($admin_data);
    }
}
```

Expected result: I want to remove whole array element, where array key less than 2. I wish to get only array with more than 1 key count like  below:

```
1111, 
    Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 1132
            )
    
        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 1133
            )
    
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are trying to unset elements within your "$admin_data" array, however you call `unset` on the array itself. If you pass the index of the array element into your loop, with the element itself, then you can check if the element has less than two inner elements, and unset that element accordingly.

```
$elementsToRemove = [];
foreach($admin_data as $index => $key) {
    if (count($key) < 2) {
        $elementsToRemove[] = $index;
    }
}

$newArray = array_diff_key($admin_data, array_flip($elementsToRemove));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood, but if you have an array of arrays and want to remove the inner arrays with less than 2 elements, you could do:

```php
<?php

$original = [
    ["a"],
    ["b", "c"],
];

$filtered = array_filter(
    $original,
    function ($innerArray) {
        return count($innerArray) >= 2;
    }
);

print_r($filtered);
```

The result is

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => b
            [1] => c
        )

)
```

[PHP Fiddle](https://3v4l.org/iigWQ)

Comment: i have tried but all arrays become empty now -> 1102,
Array
(
)
1111,
Array
(
) should return 1111 id data

Comment: it's not working can you please recheck?

Comment: my data is different look like this -> $original = [["a"]]; $original = [["b"],["c"]];  not a single array splitted into multiple separate array's

Answer (score 0):

Check again your code, it contains some logical problems:

```
foreach ($admin_data as $key) {
    if (count($admin_data) < 2) {
        unset($admin_data);
    }
}
```

If `$admin_data` has one item, the `if (count($admin_data) < 2)` test is true and
`unset($admin_data);` is executed. That means (simplifying) that the all the contents of `$admin_data` are deleted.
If `$admin_data` has two or more items, the `if (count($admin_data) < 2)` test is never true. And it is so for each iteration.
Both cases are not logical, because you do not need the `foreach` loop for this test to work. Besides, you might not want to delete `$admin_data` contents.

What you need to do, is to iterate through `$admin_data` items, check the item to see if it is an array and if that array has one item, remove the item from the `$admin_data` array. Or you could create another array only with the valid items.

Here is a possible example of both:

```
/* unset the item if it is an array with one item */
foreach ($admin_data as $key => $value) {
    if (is_array($value) && count($value) === 1) {
        unset($admin_data[$key]);
    }
}

/* create a new array with the valid items */
$valid_admin_data = [];
foreach ($admin_data as $key => $value) {
    if (is_array($value) && count($value) > 1) {
        $valid_admin_data[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

---

I would also suggest you to read again the [foreach documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php). Also, be consistents with names of variables, since it helps avoid misunderstandings: for instance, `foreach ($admin_data as $key)` could be better named to `foreach ($admin_data as $value)`, since with one variable, you extract the value of current item.